Overpass Turbo: filter needed tags in output
There is the opportunity to fetch only tags without geometry by specifying "out tags;".
However, it:

doesn't allow me to filter out tags which are not needed (for example, I only need "name" and "speed") - it is extremely important for me, because it helps against Overpass limitations on query size. Otherwise, queries with all tags listed become too bulky.
doesn't allow me to bring the geometry too, but it is also crucial for me.

What could you recommend me? I was playing around with similar queries in Overpass, but to no avail so far.
For example:
[out:json]
[date:"2013-12-31T23:59:59Z"]
[maxsize:1073741824]
[timeout:600]
[bbox:{{bbox}}];
(
  way["highway"~"(motorway|trunk|primary|secondary)"]
  ["name"]
  ["speed"]
  ["geometry"];
);
(._;>;);
out body;

Something similar to this won't work either:
[out:json]
[date:"2013-12-31T23:59:59Z"]
[bbox:{{bbox}}];
(
  nw["highway"~"(motorway|trunk|primary|secondary)"]
  ["name"]
  ["speed"]
  ["geometry"];
);
(._;>;);
out tags;


E.g. [out:json];{{geocodeArea:Mikstat}}->.searchArea;way["highway"~"(motorway|trunk|primary|secondary)"](area.searchArea);out geom; delivers 820 lines. You want remove about 100 lines with maxspeed, oneway, ...? Right? Otherwise give please an example of the result.

No, I don't want to remove any lines, only keys (most of them). It doesn't matter whether there are values for these keys, or they are null, it just should return these specific keys (for example, "name", "maxspeed", "lit"...). As far as I understand from the documentation, Overpass returns all or nothing in this case (out body or out meta): https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#out

Return of specific keys is possible with the csv option:
[out:csv (name, maxspeed; true; " | ")] 
[timeout:10]
[bbox:{{bbox}}];
way["highway"~"(motorway|trunk|primary|secondary)"];
out;

If the coordinates of the way shall be output too, a slight misuse of the csv output is required:
[out:csv (print; false)] 
[timeout:10]
[bbox:{{bbox}}];
way["highway"~"(motorway|trunk|primary|secondary)"];
foreach -> .setWay {
  .setWay; > -> .setNodes;
  make x print = u(t["name"] + " | " + t["maxspeed"]) + " | " + setNodes.set(" " + lat() + ", " + lon()); out;
};

If the output shall be in json format, this text (lat, lon, ...) must be added accordingly inside the make strings.
